# a href to upper

Tags: jquery

I have a div that contains a list of spans. And each span has a link. Is there a way to convert all of the link text to upper case?

```
<div>
  <span><a href="#">abc</a></span>
  <span><a href="#">def</a></span>
<div>
```

Thanks,

rod.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
div span a { text-transform:uppercase; }
```

Comment: I'd use `div > span > a`, but that's just me.

Comment: I would use the id of the div in his real page. This is a trivial example though just to show text-transform., and it's probably not necessary to use that selector. Yours wouldn't work in IE6.

Answer (score 2):

use the CSS text-transform:

```
div span a { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('div span a').css('text-transform', 'uppercase');
```

Answer (score 2):

.

```
$('div span a').text().toUpperCase()
```

Or you can use the CSS' `text-transform:uppercase;` as well (which is ideal, you don't need jQuery actually)